# How to update folder in master branch when updating a branch using GIT?

Tags: git, version-control

Here is the problem. I'm my git repo(Laravel application) I have three branches `master`, `dev` and `html`.

**master branch(Laravel application)**

```
...
public
resources
    |-assets
        |-sass
routes
...
```

**html branch**

```
...
sass
...
```

What I need to do is to update the laravel application's `sass` directory when updating the `sass` directory in the `html` branch.

I tried creating a `submodule` in master branch but it seems it's not the right way.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In general, managing completely different things in branches in the same repository is not a good idea. It's useful to use branches as a development strand that eventually ends up being merged in your main branch. Merging branches that have little in common (only a single of many folders, for example) is always somewhat painful.

A submodule approach would work here. You would need to create a separate repository for `sass` and integrate this repository as a submodule to your main repository, i.e. replacing the `sass` folder in your main repository with the newly created submodule. See the [git documentation on Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for further information on submodules.